# Trouble with C# Panel/Picturebox

Tags: c#, c++, wcf, dll, handle

I'm having a trouble developping an solution in C++/C#.
I have a DLL which is managed by a Windows Service and a user application which communicates with this service through WCF and Sockets.
The DLL manages a Video Capture board, and it have a function that writes in a window handle (from a picturebox or a panel) the video that it's capturing.

What i'm trying to do: Create a picturebox and pass the handle trough WCF to the service which calls the DLL function startpreview with this handle.

What is the problem: When i run the Service Proccess as an user application, everything works fine, but when i run as a Windows Service, the startpreview function doesn't writes on my handle.

Someone knows how can i solve this?
Best Regards.

@Edit

This code creates the picturebox and attaches at a flowlayoutpanel.
This is executed in the user application which communicates with the service through WCF (WCFVideoMethods.ClientStartPreview).

```
                    PictureBox videoPanel = new PictureBox();
                    videoPanel.Width = flpMonitor.Width;
                    videoPanel.Height = flpMonitor.Height;


                    /// Se for necessário invoke, invoca o metodo de adicionar um componente ao flowlayoutpanel
                    if (flpMonitor.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        flpMonitor.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                        {
                            flpMonitor.Controls.Add(videoPanel);
                        }));
                    }
                    /// Caso contrário, chama o método normalmente.
                    else
                    {
                        flpMonitor.Controls.Add(videoPanel);
                    }

                    /// Se for necessário invoke para o panel de video, invoca o metodo de inicializar o preview nele
                    if (videoPanel.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        videoPanel.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                            {
                                WCFVideoMethods.ClientStartPreview(selectedPos, videoPanel.Handle, new Rectangle(0, 0, videoPanel.Size.Width, videoPanel.Size.Height), true, 0x0080, 20, isAudioActive);
                            }));
                    }
                    /// caso contrário, chama o metodo normalmente.
                    else
                    {
                        WCFVideoMethods.ClientStartPreview(selectedPos, videoPanel.Handle, new Rectangle(0, 0, videoPanel.Size.Width, videoPanel.Size.Height), true, 0x0080, 20, isAudioActive);
                    }
```

This is the StartPreview Method executed on the Service

```
 public Boolean StartPreview(int posNo, IntPtr _handle, Rectangle _rect, Boolean _ovl, int _format, int _rate, Boolean isAudioActive)
    {
        Boolean ret = true;
        int channel = GetPosChannel(posNo);
        if (!startPrev(channel, _handle, _rect, _ovl, _format, _rate))
        {
            ret = false;
        }

        if (isAudioActive)
        {
            if (!startAudioPrev(channel))
            {
                ret = false;
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

The startPrev (the method that i need to write into the handle) is a delegate of a C++ DLL method, and i don't have access to the code.....

Comment: Show some example code so other can understand your issues and you got proper answer?

Comment: you want to add the GUI for a windows service?

Comment: Nope. Shortly, i want that the service write into a windows form handle

Comment: So is the windows form handle created by service? or passed from the client program?

Comment: Passed from the client program. The Service receives the handle by a WCF method called in the client. One of the parameters is the handle.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot interact with the desktop from an windows service... well short of. There is an interact with desktop option which you set from the properties window of the service, but that is kind of flaky.

An alternative I can suggest is that you queue up your picture buffers in your service and expose an an api via wcf/sockets to send up the buffers in a first in first out manner. 
On your application you can have a timer which would get those buffers and render them in your picturebox